# how to use ngFor in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular. I see across constructors,template,selector,etc. i have no idea. I know $scope,$rootscope, module and controller. With these I have written a code for ngFor.I believe before nfFor we had ngRepeat in angular1. please correct it.

```
 <html ng-app="moduleA">

 <head>
 <title> Collections

 </title>
 <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-
bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script 
 src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js">
 </script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-
bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

 <body>
  <script>

   angular.module('moduleA')
  .controller('SubjectController',function($scope,$rootscope){

        $scope.todos = [
        { id: 1, title: 'Learn AngularJS', description: 'Learn,Live,Laugh AngularJS', done: true },
        { id: 2, title: 'Explore hibernate', description: 'Explore and use hibernate instead of jdbc', done: true },
        { id: 3, title: 'Play with spring', description: 'spring seems better have a look', done: false },
        { id: 4, title: 'Try struts', description: 'No more labour work..use struts', done: false },
        { id: 5, title: 'Try servlets', description: 'Aah..servlets stack seems cool..why dont u try once', done: false }
    ];
    });
</script>

<div ng-controller="moduleA">

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Done?</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ngFor="let todo of todos">
                <td> {{todo.id}}</td>
                <td> {{todo.title}}</td>
                <td> {{todo.description}}</td>
                <td> {{todo.done}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You **`cannot`** use **`ngFor`** with angularjs, you can use **[`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)** to iterate over a collection.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos">
```

DEMO

```js
  angular.module('moduleA',[])
  .controller('SubjectController',function($scope){

        $scope.todos = [
        { id: 1, title: 'Learn AngularJS', description: 'Learn,Live,Laugh AngularJS', done: true },
        { id: 2, title: 'Explore hibernate', description: 'Explore and use hibernate instead of jdbc', done: true },
        { id: 3, title: 'Play with spring', description: 'spring seems better have a look', done: false },
        { id: 4, title: 'Try struts', description: 'No more labour work..use struts', done: false },
        { id: 5, title: 'Try servlets', description: 'Aah..servlets stack seems cool..why dont u try once', done: false }
    ];
    });
```

```html
<html ng-app="moduleA">

 <head>
 <title> Collections
 </title>
 <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-
bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script 
 src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js">
 </script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-
bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <script>

 
</script>

<div ng-controller="SubjectController">

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Done?</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <td> {{todo.id}}</td>
                <td> {{todo.title}}</td>
                <td> {{todo.description}}</td>
                <td> {{todo.done}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: Still its not working .giving output-
# Title Description Done?
{{todo.id}} {{todo.title}} {{todo.description}} {{todo.done}}

Comment: Check the demo also ng-controller should be SubjectController

Answer (score 4):

As others mentioned, `ngFor` is not a part of AngularJS

However, you can create function on `$rootScope` to simply generate a dummy array for `ngRepeat` as following:

```
/**
* Generates range for ngRepeat
* @param start
* @param stop
* @param increment
*/
$rootScope.generateRange = function(start, stop, increment) {
    let a = [];

    for(; start < stop; ) {
        a[start] = start;
        start += increment;
    }

    return a;
};
```

You can use it like this in your views:

```
<!-- Generates 3 star icons -->
<span class="active" ng-repeat="i in generateRange(0, 3, 1)">
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</span>
```